# Libraries for screen analyzing tool

Tags: python, monitoring, screen-scraping, video-processing

I would like to create a tool for a real time strategy game that I like.
The idea would be to analyze the game window to track information (ressources, score, ...), analyze them and plot their evolution in real time on a side-monitor, and save them for post-game analysis.

I don't think I have access to in-game information in another way than the screen (if experts think otherwise, I'm listening!).
So, my approach would be to get a video stream of the game window, do some simple video processing, some OCR, and create a GUI.

Looking around, I cannot find a way to do the video capture in Python. Is there a way to get a video stream of a display?

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Fipi

Comment: On SO [recommendation questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) are considered off-topic.

Comment: OK, I changed the formulation as recommanded in the post you mentionned.